# Div Tile expands with text, how do i prevent this (tried overflow:hidden)

Tags: html, css

The div expands if i have a lot of text `copy text paste`. 
I want the div to stay the same height no matter how much text goes inside.
I know CSS comes before HTML, thought this was better for seeing a solution.

```css
#containerTiles .tilesText {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#tiles {
  height: 33.34%;
  width: 33.34%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 66.68%;
  left: 50.01%;
  background: #3366CC;
  box-shadow: 5px 7px 0px 0px grey;
  transition: all ease .35s;
  border: solid 2px white;
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

#tiles:hover {
  top: 65.12%;
  left: 48.9%;
  box-shadow: 5px 7px 0px 0px #003c85;
  transition: all ease .35s;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerTiles">
  <a href='test.php'>
    <div id="tiles">
      <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class='tilesText'>copy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text paste</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: what is '#tilesManager8'?

Comment: @Ramineghbalian I edited the code. Should be #tiles. I wanted to clear too much info on the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `display: table` to `display: block` and set `max-height: 33.34%; overflow-y: auto;`  so with this style if the height of the entered text exceeds the container (#tiles) height, the container is scrollable.

```css
#containerTiles .tilesText {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#tiles {
  height: 33.34%;
  max-height: 33.34%;
  width: 33.34%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 66.68%;
  left: 50.01%;
  background: #3366CC;
  box-shadow: 5px 7px 0px 0px grey;
  transition: all ease .35s;
  border: solid 2px white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

#tiles:hover {
  top: 65.12%;
  left: 48.9%;
  box-shadow: 5px 7px 0px 0px #003c85;
  transition: all ease .35s;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerTiles">
  <a href='test.php'>
    <div id="tiles">
      <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class='tilesText'>copy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text pastecopy text paste</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: But i use `display:table` for centering the text horizontal and vertical

Comment: I changed my answer, I set `display:flex` and `justify-content:center; align-items: center;`